Error GAM 5 con SSO
cómo están?
Quería consultar si alguien conoce el origen del error GAM 5.
Tengo un portal que permite mediante GAM el SSO con aplicaciones varias (gx también).
Al actualizar a GX18 U8, tanto el portal como algunas apps clientes, comenzó a dar el error GAM5 "El identificador de usuario no es válido" cuando invocamos un recurso privado de la aplicación cliente (home).
Utilizando la misma bd de gam pero con aplicaciones (portal y app clientes ) con U7 o inferior no da el error.
Creé una BD nueva y configuré el sso entre portal en u8 y una aplicación cliente y también da el error (por si hubiera algun tema de metadatos o migraciones).
Estoy con gx18 u8 java web, tomcat 10.1 y java open 21.
Todo esto ejecutado localmente.
Saludos

Por las dudas utilizo autenticación local (GX como IDP)

Solución configurar la aplicación cliente y su remote authentication para enviar el scope que se necesite:
"Ese error se debe a que en la autenticación GAMRemote o GAMRemote REST la aplicación cliente no solicita al IDP ningún dato identificador del usuario como pueden ser el user_guid, user_email, user_name o user_externalId. Para solucionarlo en el tipo de autenticación GAMRemote o GAMRemote REST pedir al IDP tanto el gam_user_data o uno de los siguientes scopes: user_guid, user_email, user_name o user_externalId."
